# CSS styling or not the scrollbars

Tags: css, scrollbar, styling

My question is:

I know i can style scroll bars in my website, but i'm wondering why nobody does?

Is there any reason why scrollbars are always default in all websites out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is that you have two choices, use a [javascript plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960555/styling-browser-scrollbar), or use [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser) which is mainly supported in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

The main reason customized scrollbar styling isn't the norm is the varying degrees of CSS support by the major browsers, the lack of consistency in the support present, and the fact the alternative of using a JS plugin may be unsuitable in some contexts and can be perceived as over complication vs the relative benefits of having styled scrollbars. For something as simple as as scrollbar styling you can find yourself implementing a large amount of code for little gain.

As covered in the above links- there is also a large school of thought that changing something like scrollbars, which is an integral part of OS UX, is a no go in terms of good UI.

Comment: sure but i'm wondering why anybody style scrollbars , my question is not how to :)

Comment: ok but border-radius is not fully supported but it's used :P

Comment: But its not a component of the general operating environment within which the users browser and rendered pages falls within. A scrollbar is a component that exists and is used widely outside the context of the browser, and is typically (in by far the majority) of implementations in the OS, untouched and standard. Changing for a webpage serves little purpose vs disrupting the users familiarity with anticipated UX/UI

Comment: ok so styling scrollbars can cause a negative response from users, damn i tohught it could cause a positive one :P